# Multi-pattern regex in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I read html page and try to fetch 1st match of url that 1) does not have 'css' word inside href="" part and 2) has either word "support" or "help" within link anchor. I need href="" part only.

Here's what I got:

```
 print re.findall('href=\"([^!(css)]*?)\"*?>[^<]*(?:support|help)*[^<]*<', page_html, re.I)[0]
```

Comment: this `[^!(css)]*` won't do the thing you want.

Comment: could you post an example?

Comment: <a href="http://domain/internal-page.html">help section</a>

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup for this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a\s+(?=[^>]*?href="((?:(?!css).)*?)")[^>]*?>(?=[^<]*?(?:support|help))
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/VnzzbiexBS)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
print re.findall(r'href=\"((?:(?!css).)*?)\">[^<]*?(?:support|help)[^<]*<', page_html, re.I)
```